# C# Reflection - find first method in the stacktrace that wasn't part of the constructor for this object

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I am trying to use reflection to find the location that an object is being constructed from (where the "new A()" occurs in code), and store this for debugging purposes. This is for a framework, many classes will inherit from the base class, with varying inheritance depths, so I can't just go up the stacktrace a constant amount.

```
class A
{
     public string Origin {get; private set;}

     public A()
     {
     Origin = // reflection goes here
     }
}

class B : A
{
     public B()
     {
     }
}

class C : A
{
     B b = new B()
}

class X
{
     void M()
     {
         var b=new B()
         var c=new C()

         /* desired values:
         b.Origin = "X.M"
         c.Origin = "X.M"
         c.B.Origin = "C..ctor"
         */
    }
}
```

So far I have:

```
var stacktrace = new StackTrace()
var i = 0;
while(stacktrace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().IsConstructor)
{
    i++
}
var method = stacktrace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod();
Origin = method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name;
```

This works, except for C.B.Origin - because B is constructed in the constructor of C, this still returns X.M

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the B isn't being instantiated in a constructor?

Comment: sorry to disappoint, but what you need is not reflection, it's de-"compiling" the MSIL into a C# method. Otherwise, all you will see is some IL operations.

Comment: If B is instantiated in a non-constructor method, then I want to find that method & print its name & location. But I can do that already (using the code above) - it's just dealing with B being created in the constructor of another object that that code can't handle.

Comment: _"except for ideally I could also cope with the case where C inherits from A"_ -- what do you mean by "cope with"? What behavior do you want in that case? And given that construction of the current object provides a consistent, predictable layout of the stack frames, why do you need to walk the stack at all? Why not just look back a fixed number of frames (e.g. 1)? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the scenarios for you that don't do what you want, along with a precise description of what you _do_ want.

Comment: Have amended question in the hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have come up with - it may get confused with edge cases (if class C's constructor creates another object of type C - or a type derived from C) - but it deals with everything I need

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
var i = 0;
var myType = GetType();
while (stackTrace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().IsConstructor 
       && stackTrace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(myType))
{
    i++;
}
var methodCallingTheConstructor = stackTrace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod();
```